# How can I extend a hard disk in Ubuntu logical volume

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, hard-drive, vmware, lvm

When I installed Ubuntu 16.04 I selected logical volume management.
I created a virtual machine with 40GB Hard disk.

The I cloned that to a new machine with Hard disk 100. but when I check `df -h` it still shows 40GB.

Is there any way to increase it?

Comment: When searching the web for tutorials you may find something useful/helpful if you use "resize partition" and "grow filesystem" each in combination with "Ubuntu"

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f`?

Comment: [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) is related, but I don't think anything there actually answers this question about resizing LVM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose there is one LVM partition (except from `/boot` and maybe `EFI`), depending on the configuration of your virtual disk. As you choose LVM, you may proceed as follows:

Start `gparted` in the virtual machine, select the system disk, and create a new partition in the free space with type 'LVM'. You could also do this from the commandline with `fdisk`or `gdisk`, ifyou are used to. Remember the name of the newly created partition. For now say it's `/dev/sda4`.

Next, from commandline execute:

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/sda4  # to make the partition available for LVM
```

Now find out the name of your LVM volume group:

```
sudo vgdisplay
```

Remember the name of the volume group (say it is `vg0`). Then execute

```
sudo vgextend vg0 /dev/sda4
```

Again, find out the name of your logical volume

```
sudo lvdisplay
```

Say the volume's name is `vg0-root`. Then

```
sudo lvresize -r -l 100%VG vg0-root
```

should increase the logical volume `vg0-root`to the possible maximum (option `-l 100%VG`) and resize the filesystem as well (option `-r`). The online resize of the (mounted) filesystem depends on your kernel; current kernels with ext2/3/4 filesystem support expansion of mounted filesystems.

An other solution would be to extend the partition itself with `gparted`, then use `pvresize` (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343474/lvextend-dont-find-free-space/343477#343477), but for that you would have to boot Live Ubuntu from a CD or ISO, as you cannot increase a mounted partition through `gparted`.

If you could post some more information to your question (output of `df`, `fdisk -l`, `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay`), I could give you additional hints and correct my answer to fit your configuration.

Comment: Note: mounted partitions can be increased. And often decreased too (e.g. btrfs although not ext4).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use KDE Partition Manager 3.0 using a live cd (the version in 16.04 is too old, 17.04 is fine though).

It supports both LUKS and LVM operations, so no need to touch command line at all.