# apt install crashed because of full hdd and dpkg --reconfigure does not work anymore (because of full hdd)

Tags: apt, hard-drive, dpkg, crash, storage

The title says it...
Is there any way of removing programs without needing tu reconfigure before?
I don't know how to fix this issue. Is there a `lockfile` or so that i can delete?

I already tried to delete stuff but there is only Software on it! It is running Ubuntu 18.04 Server!

```
SSD: 8GB
Fujitsu Futuru 700S
/dev/sda1        7624872 7608488         0  100% /
```

Comment: ey why edit????

Comment: add the output of `df  | grep sd` to your post.

Comment: here u go but wont help :P

Comment: 8 GB is very little disk space for more than a very basic Ubuntu installation. It will often end up in situation like this. What are the content of `/boot' ? Are there any files in your home directory you can backup and delete ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to do some clean up

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
```

Comment: wants dpkg reconfigure (insert facepalm here)

Comment: Maybe remove some old logs from /var/log/

Comment: think there like 1KB each

Comment: after: /dev/sda1        7624872 7413488         0  100% /

Comment: before: /dev/sda1        7624872 7608488         0  100% /

Answer (score -1):

If you are using LVM on this server you could extend your HDD space on a different drive like an UBS-drive. [How can I extend a hard disk in Ubuntu logical volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884684/how-can-i-extend-a-hard-disk-in-ubuntu-logical-volume)

Comment: i dont have LVM!

Comment: dont even know LVM rly

Comment: With time you will @HACKER3000 :-)!

Comment: LVM is nice - you should try it https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-lvm-concepts-terminology-and-operations

Comment: Do you have a swap - partition?

Comment: 8GB = no space 4 that

Comment: that is true ...